# What is supposed to be routing order in a multi-module Angular application using eager loading?

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

What I mean is that if I have:

- app.module with routes: 'home', '**'(redirect to home)
- feature.module with routes: 'feature1', 'feature2' registered via RoutingModule.forChild()

and eager-load feature.module into app.module using import.

When I print out the routes:

```
  constructor(private router: Router)
  {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.router.config);
  }
```

I get the feature routes ahead of the .forRoot() routes in the array. I.e.,

```
 {path: "feature1", component: ƒ}
 {path: "feature2", component: ƒ}
 {path: "home", component: ƒ}
 {path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full"}
```

Is this how it works, that every imported module with .forChild() gets all of its routes inserted at the 0-index by default?

The reason I ask is this would obviously affect the router matching of URLs. Would a better practice be to define the full router states in order as a single array and register that in the .forRoot() instead of dividing up the registrations into multiple modules as a way to fully control the order?